# vuetify v-data-table rows per page options doesnt show

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

This codepen contains the code that I am working with, however I was not able to recreate my exact error with how codepen works,

https://codepen.io/benwasin97/pen/eYveZGL

```
<v-card id="card" class="card">

</v-card>
```

How the code should be structured is that Everything except the v-data-table is in its own component and this component has a slot. I then put v-data-table inside the component by using the slot of the component which wraps it around the v-card.

However when I try this on my local machine, the v-menu drop down menu "rows per page options" no longer shows up in my table.

I have some hunches that it doesn't show up because i am putting the v-data-table inside of a slot in another component? because this seems to cause the issue but not 100% sure.

If anyone has worked with v-data-tables and has this issue or knows what could be wrong, please let me know! Thank you

Comment: I had this problem while mounting my app with v-data-table inside another application. My "rows per page drop down" always appeared somewhere else on the site. The drop down doesn't seem to be attached to the menu button. In the end I used a custom pagination instead.

Comment: interesting, is the custom pagination easy?

Comment: Easy is relative to your skills, but I learned it pretty quickly. The documentation has a good example. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-pagination

Comment: In the data table docs there isn't a items slot. And also I don't see the father component wish you want to place the data table inside. You may consider https://codesandbox.io/ for the sample code instead of codepen.